How to update a wordpress page from .NET Core
I have downloaded the WordPressPCL example project in https://github.com/wp-net/WordPressPCL.
What I need is to update a page or post of Wordpress but I don't find any example.
All I find are examples of how to get one or many pages or posts, or how to create a new page.
But how to update the date or title of a page? In my attempts I receive "BadRequest" or "NotFound" error responses.
I can get pages without problem doing this:
public async Task<DataTable> LoadPagessAsync()
{
    var client = new RestClient("https://myfoowebname.com/wp-json/wp/v2/"); //obviously this url is fake

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

    int page = 1;
    bool morePages = true;

    while (morePages)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest($"pages?Authorization=Bearer{Web.Authorization}", Method.Get);
        request.AddParameter("per_page", 100);
        request.AddParameter("page", page);

        var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request, Method.Get);

        if (response.IsSuccessful)
        {
            var pages = JArray.Parse(response.Content);

            foreach (var pageItem in pages)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(pageItem["id"].Value<int>(), pageItem["title"]["rendered"].Value<string>(), pageItem["date"].Value<DateTime>());
            }

            if (pages.Count < 100)
            {
                morePages = false;
            }
            else
            {
                page++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error getting pages: " + response.ErrorMessage);
            morePages = false;
        }
    }

    return table;
}

And I'm trying to update a page doing this:
public async Task UpdatePageDate(int pageId, DateTime date)
{
    var client = new RestClient("https://myfoowebname.com/wp-json/wp/v2/"); //obviously this url is fake
    var request = new RestRequest($"page/{pageId}?Authorization=Bearer{Web.Authorization}", Method.Post);
    request.AddJsonBody(new { date = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ") });
    var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);

    if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error updating {pageId}: " + response.ErrorMessage);
    }
}

Changing POST to PUT doesn't work either.
Any idea how to do it?

Was there something in the documentation with examples that you are struggling with?

"I have downloaded the WordPressPCL example project" Yet you don't appear to be using the WordpressPCL package on nuget

Didn't see that documentation neither the WordPressPCL Nuget package. I'll go for it. Thx

It works perfectly with WordPressPCL library.
I login with this:
Client = new WordPressClient(Web.BaseUrl);
Client.Auth.UseBasicAuth(Username, ApplicationPassword);

Where ApplicationPassword is the password generated in user profile of the Wordpress site.
And this for update the pages:
public async Task<List<Page>> UpdatePagesDateAsync(List<Page> pagesToUpdate, DateTime newDate)
{
    foreach (var page in pagesToUpdate)
    {
        page.Date = newDate;
    }

    var updatedPages = await Task.WhenAll(pagesToUpdate.Select(page => Client.Pages.UpdateAsync(page)));

    return updatedPages.ToList();
}

Thx!
